# Hebrew numerals

Tags: numbering, polyglossia, hebrew

There appears to be three different numbering commands in the `polyglossia` package. Which one is the most correct to use?

I can understand the argument for the `\Hebrewnumeralfinal` one since it seems correct to have the final letters show appropriately. But there is also a difference in the way that the other two commands generate a numeral, which is a bit confusing to me.

If there are any Hebrew native speaking TeX.SX members, I would appreciate your input.

This is a MWE.

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=hebrew]{hebrew}

\begin{document}
ελληνικά \greeknumeral{1863}

Hebrew: עִבְרִית\\
\hebrewnumeral{1750}
\Hebrewnumeral{1750}
\Hebrewnumeralfinal{1750}\\
\hebrewnumeral{1}
\Hebrewnumeral{1}
\Hebrewnumeralfinal{1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between `\hebrewnumeral` and `\Hebrewnumeral` is whether or not the "gershayim" are included - these are the marks that look like a double quotation mark and appear before the last character. They're used, broadly speaking, to indicate that a set of several letters is not an ordinary word (e.g., it's a number or an acronym). Whether you want them may depend on the context in which you're printing the number, but I would advise using them (and therefore the `\H` version) in most contexts.

More information at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershayim .

(Disclaimer: my Hebrew is decent but I'm not a native speaker.)

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate on Ant's answer:

Hebrew numbers are rarely written using the final forms of letters; 120 is much more commonly expressed as ק"כ than ק"ך.  There are exceptions, of course, but they are rather esoteric, so I wouldn't worry about them.

As to when the gershayim are used, this typically depends on custom and context.  Where it is clear that what's being presented is a number, they are quite often excluded.  Numbered chapter headings, for example, are usually written without them, and often the date (of the month), although years are almost always written with:

פרק יא

כג תשרי תשע"ב

Comment: Thanks Aryeh for the clarification - I wasn't aware that gershayim can be omitted in the cases you mention. To annotate for the benefit of non-Hebrew readers who might be idly browsing this question: these two examples are "Chapter 11", where 11 = יא has no gershayim, and "23 Tishrei 5772" - today! - where 23 = כג has no gershayim but (5)772 = תשע"ב does.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will mostly use it on the basis of a chapter and verse model as appears in the Tanakh. I will keep your advice in mind though for any future Hebrew projects.

Comment: @AryehLeibTaurog: Actually, I don't think it's that esoteric. These forms have their place sometimes... especially when the word, taken not as a number, has a meaning of its own.