# Hebrew in TeXShop

Tags: languages, mactex, texshop, hebrew

I tried to install Hebrew in my LaTeX.
I'm using TeXShop and I also have Texmaker for MacBook.
I downloaded already [IvriTeX](http://ivritex.sourceforge.net/) and [Culmus](http://culmus.sourceforge.net/), but I don't know how to install it.
I found [this tutorial](http://www.sciencebits.com/HebrewOnTexShop) on the web, but I don't understand it.
Can someone be more clear and simple about the installation of Hebrew support?

[image: this was on web (http://www.sciencebits.com/HebrewOnTexShop)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about `IvriTex` and `Culmus`, but you can do Hebrew by just using the `Babel` package which is probably already installed for you. (Use [MacTex](http://www.tug.org/mactex/) to get the best setup in my opinion.)

Then run an example like [this](http://ivritex.sourceforge.net/HOWTO/heblatex_guide.html) from `IvriTex's` example page:

```
\documentclass{article}
% There may be a number of languages. The main document language is 
% the *last* of them
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}

\begin{document}
כדי לכתוב משהו באנגלית חייבים להשתמש במקרו הבא: \L{Hello, world}. וכאן
ממשיכים לכתוב בעברית. טקסט נוסחאות תמיד יהיה בכיוון שמאל-לימין:
$a_1+a_{2}=c^{2}$ .

כעת נתחיל חלק באנגלית:

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
Hello, World. Hebrew text inside English paragraph must come inside the
macro R: \R{בוקר טוב עולם}.

This is the preffered way to set the language.
\end{otherlanguage}

דרך אחרת לעבור לאנגלית:

\unsethebrew
Yet Another English Paragraph

And another paragraph
\sethebrew

פסקה שמינית ואחרונה )באמת(.
\end{document}
```

---

This is an [MWE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28648/7093) using the `polyglossia` package, which I think in turn uses `babel`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=hebrew]{hebrew}

\begin{document}
ελληνικά \greeknumeral{1863}

Hebrew: עִבְרִית\\
\hebrewnumeral{1750}
\Hebrewnumeral{1750}
\Hebrewnumeralfinal{1750}\\
\hebrewnumeral{1}
\Hebrewnumeral{1}
\Hebrewnumeralfinal{1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't compile your first example under any engine using a full TeXLive 2014 installation with nothing additional. And `Polyglossia` is a replacement for `babel`; it does not use `babel`.

Comment: I tried this, it works  McGafter

Comment: @user203577 I'm glad if it is of help. You can accept the answer if you find it fulfils the need.

Comment: @AndrewCashner I got it from that site mentioned, have you removed the line numbers?